# how to find if the check box list is selected or not in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

How to get selected index in a check box list in asp.net. Should I loop through to find whether the list box is selected or can i get to know without doing that. I want to do this

if(Checkboxlist selected)
{do this}
else
{do this}

how to find if the check box list is selected or not in asp.net

```
int roleselected = ckl_EditRole.Items.SelectedIndex;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For CheckBoxList, `SelectedIndex` will give you just the first selected index in the CheckBoxList. If it's not -1, then something was selected. This may be enough for what you're looking for.

```
if( ckl_EditRole.SelectedIndex != -1 )
{
// Do Something
}
```

But, since the CheckBoxList can have multiple selections, you probably want to loop through the Items and look for the selected ones.

```
foreach( ListItem li in ckl_EditRole.Items )
{
    if( li.Selected )
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to get index of the selected checkbox as given by your code, you can also achieve this via Linq(without forloop) as below.

```
ckl_EditRoleItems.OfType<ListItem>().Where(p=>p.Selected).Select(p => ckl_EditRoleItems.Items.IndexOf(p)).ToArray<int>();
```

This statement will return an array of int which will contain the index of the check boxes that are selected.