# A list of names with check boxes

Tags: asp.net, .net, listview, checkbox

Using asp.net I need to make a list of names and IDs and have a check box with each row

For example

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="id"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But it would need to be a list view and just use a layout template with it.

Probably like this

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server" id="table1" >
            <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" ></tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
            <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                <asp:Label ID="IdLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%#Eval("CFId") %>' />
            </td>
            <td id="Td2" runat="server">
                <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%#Eval("CFName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td id="Td3" runat="server">
                <asp:Checkbox ID="Checkbox" runat="server" 
                    name='<%#Eval("CFId") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

How can I get it so I can get a list of the checked check boxes from a list like this? Each line having a checkbox.

Comment: FYI, you are not using "asp". You are using "asp.net". They're not the same.

Comment: Opsie I knew that. Simple mistake

Comment: The code you posted seems reasonable, is it not doing something you want it to?

Comment: I want the `CFIds` of the selected rows.

Comment: @SmartLemon, loopthrough each `ListView` row and use `FindControl` to find label `CFId` and get that control value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server" id="table1">
            <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder">
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
            <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                <asp:Label ID="IdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CFId") %>' />
            </td>
            <td id="Td2" runat="server">
                <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CFName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td id="Td3" runat="server">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Checkbox" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:Button ID="btnGetChecked" runat="server" Text="Get Checked Items" OnClick="GetChecked" />
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        var table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("CFId");
        table.Columns.Add("CFName");

        table.Rows.Add("1", "Item 1");
        table.Rows.Add("2", "Item 2");
        table.Rows.Add("3", "Item 3");

        ListView1.DataSource = table;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void GetChecked(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    var items = ListView1.Items.Where(i => ((CheckBox)i.FindControl("Checkbox")).Checked);
    foreach (ListViewItem item in items)
    {
        Label IdLabel = item.FindControl("IdLabel") as Label;
        Label NameLabel = item.FindControl("NameLabel") as Label;

        if (IdLabel != null && NameLabel != null)
        {
            string id = IdLabel.Text;
            string name = NameLabel.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you may want to use [System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx):

```
var r = from item in list.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
        where i.Selected
        select i.Value;
```

or the same in Extension Methods syntax:

```
var r = list.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                  .Where(i => i.Selected)
                  .Select(i => i.Value);
```

Comment: How can I use it in the context of this question? And how can I get all the selected values? As in, the `CFId` of the rows selected

Comment: @SmartLemon: Probably `list.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).Select(i => i.Value)` will return values of checked items only.

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed I believe

Comment: I am getting the error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewDataItem' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'.`

Comment: @SmartLemon: Sorry, use `Cast<ListViewItem>()` instead of my initial code.

Comment: `ListViewItem does not contain a definition for Selected`

Comment: I know what I did. I'm not using a `CheckBoxList`, but how can I use a check box list like above? I am binding the data from a `DataTable`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009769/how-to-find-if-the-check-box-list-is-selected-or-not-in-asp-net should work